# Why does this LinkedList sorting algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm

I've been working on an algorithm to add elements to a linked list, and sort it when it adds the element. My code works, and I know why for the most part, but I was surprised to see this code worked for adding elements at the end of the list. Here's the code:

```
    public void add(int value)
  {
    Node currentNode;
    Node previousNode;
    Node newNode;
    if(firstNode == null)
    {
      firstNode = new Node(value,firstNode);
    }

    else
    {
     currentNode = firstNode; 
     previousNode = null;

     while(currentNode != null && value > currentNode.getValue())
     {
      previousNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
     }
       if(previousNode == null)
       {
        firstNode = new Node(value, firstNode); 
       }
       else
       {
       newNode = new Node(value,currentNode);
       previousNode.setNextNode(newNode); 
       }
    }
  }
```

So I know this would work for adding to the beginning or the middle, but how does it add to the end? I mean, if the while loop traverses to the end of the list, then currentNode is the last node, previous node is one before, so wouldn't:

```
newNode = new Node(value,currentNode);
previousNode.setNextNode(newNode);
```

never add the element to the end? Wouldn't it always add the new node between previous and current?

Comment: currentNode is null after the while statement if it gets to the end.

Comment: Does the code really work if you insert node 23 into an empty list, and then insert node 10?  I don't see where the code hooks the previous front-of-the-list to the next node of the new front-of-the-list.  Also, the design using global variable `firstNode` inherently limits you to a single list.  A better design would arrange to pass the current front-of-the-list to the function(s) and return the new front-of-the-list.

Comment: Yes it works. If a value is lower then any in the list, then  if(previousNode == null)
       {
        firstNode = new Node(value, firstNode); 
       } is called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

previousNode, as name suggests, points to a node behind current node.
When you reach the end, (This happens when value you are trying to insert is larger than any of the current elements) currentNode becomes null, but previousNode is pointing to last node. Hence previousNode.setNextNode(newNode) works fine.

Comment: ah of course. I wsa thinking currentNode would be the last node in the list, not null. I guess null IS the last